# Splash window in Java

Tags: java, awt, splash-screen

I am trying to create a splash screen that displays a gif animation. The thing about my Splash screen I want to actually make it appear after the main() function returns (Main() just creates a login screen. I want my GUI initialization to begin after the user puts in a password). In addition my splash screen should disappear after the completion of certain non-GUI background actions.

So... Can I (or should I) use awt's SplashScreen class in this scenario?

My current implementation manages to display a blank splash screen and hide it in the right time. The problem is that the gif animation is only loaded *after* the GUI is initialized. I think it is because the EDT is busy with GUI initialization and can't display animation.

I was hoping that maybe SplashScreen class would solve that issue. If anyone has any hints or tips it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) appears to suggest you can use animation.

> The splash screen can display any gif, png, or jpeg image, with
>   transparency, translucency, and animation. The figure below represents
>   an example of the Java application splash screen developed as an
>   animated gif file.

Comment: The problem is that by default The splash screen is loaded and displayed before main() starts (this can be easily fixed by set visible) but it also closes automatically when main() finishes. This is unwanted, how do i fix that?

Comment: If I following you right, after the login screen, this splash screen would appear, then after the animation is completed the main screen would appear then have this splash screen disposed?

Comment: Pretty much. A little correction: after the main screen appears there may still be some computation going in the background by a worker thread. Only after this thread is done should the splash screen be disposed of.